# Spring Cloud Config Config Server - Synchronization between several instances

Tags: spring-boot, mesos, spring-cloud-config, spring-boot-configuration

Let's say I have started to use the spring-cloud-config-server and get it working (using a git repository in background). So now I will deploy that config-server on a cluster (mesos cluster or AWS cloud etc.)

So for reliability etc. I would like to start two instances of the same config-service within a cluster. By using a service registry all other services can now connect to that config-server and get their configuration.

But the question: How can the synchronisation between those config-servers being handled... So for example If I change the configuration in the git repository and now there is some lack of time between both instance will deliver the exact same information...

Does there exist a solution for that ? Some kind of a raft census protocol / setup etc. ? Or is there the only solution not to use spring-config-server and use etcd instead or other solutions ?

**Update:**
It might be an option to make a fore-update option for the git repositories. This makes sure to get the most recent state with the drawback of performance.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Cloud Services v3.1.2 and later, you can use the periodic parameter when configuring a Config Server service instance to cause the mirror service to automatically refresh a Git repository mirror periodically

[pcf link](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-1/common/config-server/refreshing-properties.html)